# JQuery and CSS for menu reveal or hint

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists, submenu

I'm trying to figure out how I might go about alerting my audience to when a sub menu is available below a landing page in our left menu.  Currently users have to click the menu to show whether there is anything below it. I think at the top levels this is intuitive. The user sees the menu choices, picks one and clicks, then the menu opens if there's sub menus, meanwhile the content of that landing page displays on the right.  If that makes sense?

However after the second level, it's less intuitive and because we don't have any mouseover events (and don't want them) a user will have to click around to reveal any hidden content on the left menu.  So what I'd like to do is give them a visual clue. Perhaps a small icon (like a down arrow?) that indicates there is content below this level (if there is). I'm just not sure what the best approach to this is.  I was thinkign using  Jquery, but I'd have to have it look for the class name of the UL, but display the icon on the previous UL if it exists.  Any ideas?

Here's the list structure that makes up the menu for reference.  I preserved the real class names.

```html
<ul id="subnav">
    <li class=""><a target="_top" href="../index1.html" class="">Index Page 1</a>
</li>
<li class=""><a target="_top" href="../index2.html" class="">Index Page 2</a>
  <ul class="level2 subnavArrows">
  <li class=""><a target="_top" href="../sub1.html" class=" viewMore">Sub Page 1</a></li>
  <li class=""><a target="_top" href="../sub2.html" class=" viewMore">Sub Page 2</a></li>
  <li class=""><a target="_top" href="../sub3.html" class=" viewMore">Sub Page 3</a>
    <ul class="level3 subnavArrows">
      <li class=""><a target="_top" href="subsub1" class=" viewMore">Sub Sub Page 1</a></li>
      <li class=""><a target="_top" href="subsub2" class=" viewMore">Sub Sub Page 2</a></li>
      <li class=""><a target="_top" href="subsub3" class=" viewMore">Sub Sub Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
  <li class=""><a target="_top" href="../sub4.html" class=" viewMore">Sub Page 4</a></li>
  <li class=""><a target="_top" href="../sub5.html" class=" viewMore">Sub Page 5</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class=""><a target="_top" href="../index3.html" class="">Index Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm on a phone right now so can't post full code but you could use a bit of CSS trickery to target the links in level2 items that contain submenus and add a pseudo element containing the desired icon: .level2>li>a:not(:last-child):after

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this with jQuerys `has()` method:

```
$("li").has("ul").css("color","red");
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z8owpq6p/

Comment: Thanks danjah.  I'm going to try Shaggy's CSS solution first, as I'm more comfortable in that area than JS/Jquery where I can find my way around but stumble a lot.    Thanks for pointing out this method though.  I can see how it would work so I'll come back to it if the style sheet solution doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so to give a slightly more in-depth answer than in my comment, this is all entirely possible with a little bit of trickery involving CSS selectors.

What you're looking to do is select the `a` elements that are direct children of `li` elements which are, in turn, direct children of your `ul` elements with class `level2`.

From that selection, then, you only want to target those `a` elements that are not the only child of their parent `li`.

You mentioned possibly using an icon of some description as your indicator so I'm going to use a pseudo element to do just that.

Here's the sample CSS:

```
.level2>li>a:not(:last-child):after{
    content:"»";
}
```

Obviously, you may want to apply a bit more style to it than that, but you get the idea.

To explain those selectors:

The `>` child selector selects only those elements that are immediate children of the parent element. ([More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors))

The `:not()` pseudo class negates the selector in its arguments. In this instance, `a` elements that are not the last child of their parent. ([More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not))

I'll assume you're familiar with [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) and [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) but have linked them up to more information, just in case.

Comment: Thanks Shaggy.  I'll give this a try before I delve into the jquery solution.

Comment: How'd you get on with it, @Etherplain?